# How i can i identify the project type as an eclipse plug-in?

Tags: java, eclipse, pde

I want to identify the type (java/c/...) of the currently selected project from an Eclipse plug-in; If possible some other information also (used libraries and what not), basically all the information surrounding the project.

I have been searching on google and here for a couple of hours now, to no avail. Can i even access the information i want without selecting some bogus Extension Point (none of the ones listed seem to fit what i want to do)? I mean, i don't want to actually add anything to Eclipse right now, i just want to print out that stuff into the console. (start small and stuff)

Sorry for the long rant, but i don't know how to better express my problem right now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A lot of this information is stored in the `.project` file in the project folder. The correct way to access the information is via the `IProject` object for the project.

The `IProject.getDescription` method returns you a `IProjectDescription` containing information about the project.

To determine the type of project you need to look at the `natures` that are defined in the project description. The `IProjectDescription.getNatureIds()` method returns an array of the nature ids. A Java project will have the `org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature` and a plug-in will have `org.eclipse.pde.PluginNature` (and a Java plug-in will have both these natures).

To find the `IProject`. If you have a selection in something like Package or Project Explorer try:

```
IResource resource = (IResource)Platform.getAdapterManager().getAdapter(obj, IResource.class);
```

or

```
IFile file = (IFile)Platform.getAdapterManager().getAdapter(obj, IFile.class);
```

the `getProject()` method of these interfaces gives you the `IProject`. You may also just be able to do:

```
IProject project = (IProject)Platform.getAdapterManager().getAdapter(obj, IProject.class);
```

`Platform` in the above is `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform` (there are other `Platform` classes in Eclipse so be sure to get the correct one).

If you just have a project name then use:

```
IProject project = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject(name);
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. But how do i even get the selected IProject? I got the activeworkbench and the selection service, problem is if i click my improvised button, the button is ofcourse the selected element.

Comment: Added info on finding `IProject` to answer

Comment: Thank you very much! Found what i needed thanks to your answer :)

Comment: Sorry, someone less competent here: you say "if you have a selection in something like Package or Project Explorer try:" + [Java line of code]... could you explain what I actually have to do to get such a line to run? Is it part of a `main` method in a .java file?? I'm lost!

Comment: @mikerodent This code has to be part of an Eclipse plugin installed in Eclipse. plugins don't use a `main` method. Code in plugins usually runs in response to some event, like a menu item being selected.